# Use class constants in definition of nested class in python

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

```
class Parent:
  separator = "|"
  
  class DataContainer:
    def __init__(self, data):
      self.data = data.split(**separator**)
```

In the following snippet, is there a way to get the value of Parent.separator into the subclass?

As a side note:
The sub-class is a data structure used only in the Parent class. Do you find this as a good design choice? Or should it be a normal class?

Comment: This is not a "subclass", you just nested a class definition, which makes one class object an attribute of another. That's it. And no, you probably shouldn't be nesting the class.

Comment: `Parent.separator`? And it's hard to tell without more context, but nested classes are generally not the best choice.

Comment: Anyway, `self.separator = "|"` would cause an error, assuming you meant `separator = "|"` you *could* use `Parent.separator`, like you would anywhere else you want to access a class attribute

Comment: Whoops. I miswrote Parent so Parent.separator did not work, sorry. Will use that.
I thought that the error was because Parent hasn't yet been defined.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. It is a specific datastructure that is not used anywhere else. Not using the class makes it difficult and defining it at the module-level seems pointless. Do you think defining it at the module-level is better? I understand there is little context

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use Parent.separator. As @juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned in the comments.